# Aura Pro X SSD upgrade for MacBook Pro Mid 2014 issue

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade

I have recently upgraded my MacBookPro with an OWC SSD after the original SSD crashed. I have not seen any issues with the system performance after performing the SMC & PRAM reset after the install. However, on running Apple Diagnostics, I am still seeing 'VDH002 - There may be issues with storage' error. The Disk Utility does not detect any issues with the drive.

Would somebody know if this actually indicates an issue with the SSD, or Apple not recognizing a third party device?

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)
Model Id: MacBookPro 11,1.
OS : macOS Mojave, version 10.14.1(18B75)
SSD : OWC Aura Pro X
```

Comment: i have same issue. my MBPR model is Macbook pro retina late 2013, i purchased this owc ssd is 1 TB, is running well. but when i open my macbook to try wake it up, my macbook have flash cant loading anything. i try to restart 2 times, becasue the first time it still cant loading with this ssd, second time i have to do running Apple Diagnostics reference code is VDH002, i have to thought this problemss should be SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a replacement hard disk, and ran it through all diagnostics including the apple system diagnostics. It passed everything except the default Apple Diagnostics with the error -  'VDH002 - There may be issues with storage' error.

So it looks like Apple Diagnostircs doesn’t recognize the OWC hard disk as good for some reason.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not expert, I do know that the OWC Auras don't provide S.M.A.R.T. drive data and that MAY be what the diagnostics is complaining about.  I too just replaced my SSDs (on two different MacBook Airs) and am seeing the VDH002 code.